# Reading $_GET after URL rewrite

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I don't know if I am approaching this correctly. Basically I have a URL

> www.mydomain.com/openings.html?jobName=accounting-manager

I want the URL to be

> www.mydomain.com/openings/accounting-manager.html

So, I added this to the .htaccess

> RewriteRule ^openings/([^/]*).html$ /openings.html?\ jobfilename=$1
>   [L]

So the URL works as intended. Now, I want to read the $_GET['jobName'] on this page so that I can get print it on the page. But after the URL rewrite the $_GET variable is not present. Is there a way to accessing? Do I need to change the rewrite or should I approach this in a different way?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the `?\ j` escape bit for? there's no reason for that `\[space]` to be in the url, because that'd become part of the query parameter's name. e.g. you'd need to be accessing `$_GET['\\ jobfilename']`, because `\[space]` means nothing to the url system.

Comment: So it should be? RewriteRule ^openings/([^/]*).html$ /openings.html?jobfilename=$1 [L]

Comment: looks better. and you can also do a `var_dump($_GET)` in your script to see ALL of the query inputs the script's receiving.

Comment: Ok. var_dump($_GET) shows array(0) { }

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php) could help?

Answer (score 1):

Its most probably because multiviews is enabled. Place this at top of .htaccess file.

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Also check out [QSA](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag for your rule.

Comment: [QSA] - query string append was what I thought of too : https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<?php
$url=explode("/", $_Server['request_url']);
print_r($url);
?>
```

you will see an array contains the url